# Searching for users using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

What would be the better approach to let a user search for other users who use the app (using Parse.com as the backend) :

1. Import all the the data in the _User table then filter t in the app when using the UISearchBar
2. Querying parse for the search term and loading the results to the tableview

Comment: Better = more efficient when handling a large amount of users

Comment: I would say option 2, it takes processing off the device and doesn't pass your whole database of users around to everyone! :S

Comment: While option 2 is "better" in the sense of less data traffic, it will have an impact on your transactions/second and therefore $

Comment: depends on the size of your database as well

Comment: I like option 2 as well. Its much better. Parse is an awesome backend!

Comment: Option 2. You don't want your application to handle that load. Your backend should be the one to find specified objects for you and just give you the results to display. Basically, what Wezly said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "right" answer. It depends entirely on how you define "better."

Option 1 likely produces superficially the best user experience, in the sense that filtering a list on the fly looks a lot more responsive. But you have to schedule downloading the user list for when the user isn't already trying to search.

Option 2 is likely more efficient. Less bandwidth, less storage. But the user had to be online to search and you probably can't do a "real time" filter unless you're on a fast network.

There may be other factors also. I didn't want to expose a list of users, for example, so I went for option 2.

Comment: Thanks, I think i will go with that option as well.